# Terraform - what is null provider?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am wondering what is the real use of terraform null provider and when to use and NOT use it.

I have gone through the Terraform docs - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/null/latest/docs  but it has been of little help.

> Null Provider
>
> The null provider is a rather-unusual provider that has constructs
> that intentionally do nothing. This may sound strange, and indeed
> these constructs do not need to be used in most cases, but they can be
> useful in various situations to help orchestrate tricky behavior or
> work around limitations.
>
> The documentation of each feature of this provider, accessible via the
> navigation, gives examples of situations where these constructs may
> prove useful.
>
> Usage of the null provider can make a Terraform configuration harder
> to understand. While it can be useful in certain cases, it should be
> applied with care and other solutions preferred when available.

Could some one eloborate on -  *but they can be useful in various situations to help orchestrate tricky behavior or work around limitations.* And provide further references to explore this provider.

--
this is how my providers.tf file looks -

```
provider "aws" {
  alias   = "primary"
  region  = "us-east-1"
  profile = "${local.primary_aws_profile}"
  version = "~> 2.70.0"
}

provider "template" {
  version = "~> 1.0"
}

provider null {
  version = "~> 1.0"
}
```

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear about the null provider?

Answer (score 6):

> Could some one eloborate on - *but they can be useful in various situations to help orchestrate tricky behavior or work around limitations*. And provide further references to explore this provider.

@Marcin answer outlines an example using a `null_resource` with `local-exec` and I thought I'd expand with a concrete example of when I have had to use one with `remote_exec`.

I had an issue where I was unable to destroy an EC2 `aws_instance` that had an `aws_volume_attachment` because the EBS volume was not detached prior to destroying. The workaround was to use a `null_resource` to unmount the volume on destroy of the instance and volume attachment.

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance" { ..snip .. }

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "data" { ..snip.. }

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "data_att" {
  device_name  = "/dev/sdf"
  volume_id    = aws_ebs_volume.data.id
  instance_id  = aws_instance.instance.id
}

resource "null_resource" "unmount_data_drive" {
  triggers = {
    public_ip = aws_instance.instance.public_ip
  }

  depends_on = [aws_volume_attachment.data_att, aws_instance.instance]

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    when       = destroy
    on_failure = continue
    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      agent       = false
      host        = self.triggers.public_ip
      user        = "ubuntu"
      private_key = file(var.key_pair)
    }
    inline = [
      "sudo umount /opt/data",
      "sudo sed -i '/opt\\/data/d' /etc/fstab"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using null resource primary  [null_resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/null/latest/docs/resources/resource):

> The primary use-case for the null resource is as a do-nothing container for arbitrary actions taken by a provisioner.

As the description writes, you use it mostly with [provisioners](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/syntax.html) such as `local-exec` and `remote-exec`.

A common scenario is to perform custom actions using `local-exec` and `remote-exec` when a number of resources gets created. Example of such case is introduction of a delay in resource creation, as shown [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/17726):

```
resource "null_resource" "before" {
}

resource "null_resource" "delay" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sleep 10"
  }
  triggers = {
    "before" = "${null_resource.before.id}"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "after" {
  depends_on = ["null_resource.delay"]
}
```